# How quickly can global means surface temperatures react to changes in CO2?

Tags: climate-change, greenhouse-gases

I am interested in whether short term (approximately decadal) variations in atmospheric CO<sub>2</sub> would be observable in the consequent variability in Global Mean Surface Temperatures (GMSTs) as a result of the greenhouse effect.  Say we had a decadal cycle in atmospheric CO<sub>2</sub>, how large would it have to be before that cycle were detectable?

I suspect it would have to be very large because of the thermal inertia of the atmosphere/ocean system, but I don't have any intuition about the magnitude of the damping this would produce.

Comment: There are studies about regional decadal variations in CO2, but it would seem like any global decadal variability would be overwhelmed by the constant global rise in CO2 levels driven by emissions.